# React Native TextInput not updating state

Tags: react-native

Well this is an embarrassing question, but I can't get this TextInput to take values I type into it.

It just deletes it as fast as I can type it - and I'm pretty sure logging this.state.code shows an empty variable.

Is it the keyboard type messing with me? Do I need to do a  `.toString()`?

```js
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        code: '12'
    }
}

<TextInput
    onChangedText={(text) => this.setState({code: text})}
    value={this.state.code}
    keyboardType='numeric'
    style={styles.input}
    placeholder='Code'
    maxLength={4}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct prop is `onChangeText`. Not `onChangedText`

Comment: shoot me. its time to take a break from coding today